# If $\underline X$ is 2. countable then one-point Alexandroff-Compactification of $X$ is metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Given:**

$\underline X = (X,T)$, a locally-compact $T_2$ space

$\alpha X := X \cup \{w\}$, where $w \not \in X$

$R = \{ A \subset \alpha X \ | \ A \cap X \in T, w \in A 
\Rightarrow X \setminus A \text{ is compact}\}$

$\underline {\alpha X} = (\alpha X,R)$

The canonical injection map $e: \underline X \longrightarrow \underline{\alpha X}$ is the Alexandroff-Compactification.

---

**Attempt:**

If $\mathcal A$ is a countable basis of $\underline{X}$, then $\mathcal B = e[\mathcal A] \cup \{ \alpha X \}$ is a countable basis of $\underline{\alpha X}$.

So, the space $\underline{\alpha X}$ is 2-nd countable. Due to compactness and $T_2$ property it is also regular.

According to the Urysohn-Metrization-Theorem, a regular 2-nd countable space is metrizable.

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti, edited.

Comment: @CCCP your $\mathcal B$ is not a base of $R$: it contains only one neighbourhood of $w$

Comment: Oh, by $e[\mathcal A]$ I mean a **family of sets**: $e[\mathcal A] = \{ e[A_1], e[A_2], e[A_3] ... \}$

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti, why isn't $\mathcal B$ a  basis of $R$ if it covers all points of $\alpha X$ and for any point $x$ inside the intersection of two sets from $\mathcal B$ there is an element of $\mathcal B$ containing that point $x$.

Comment: It is a base of *some* topology on $\alpha X$, but not of $R$, since there are open sets in $R$ that are not unions of elements of $\mathcal B$ (any nontrivial open set containing $w$)

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You attempt goes in right direction, but you need to find a countable neigborhood base at $w$. Certainly $\{ \alpha X \}$ is not.

Define
$$\mathcal C = \{ \overline A  \mid A \in \mathcal A, \overline A \text{ is compact}\} .$$
This is a countable set of compact subsets of $X$. Hence also the set $\mathcal C^*$ of all finite unions of elements of $\mathcal C$ is countable. We claim that each compact $K \subset X$ admits $C \in \mathcal C^*$ such that $K \subset C$.

Since $X$ is locally compact, each $x \in K$ has an open neigborhood $U$ with compact closure. Pick $A(x) \in \mathcal A$ such that $x \in A(x) \subset U$. Clearly $\overline{A(x)}$ is a subset of $\overline U$, thus also $\overline{A(x)}$ is compact, i.e. $\overline{A(x)} \in \mathcal C$. $K$ is covered by finitely many $A(x_i)$, therefore $K \subset \bigcup_i \overline{A(x_i)} \in \mathcal C^*$.

Thus
$$\mathcal W = \{\alpha X \setminus C \mid C \in \mathcal C^*\} $$
is a countable family of open neigborhoods of $w$ which by construction is a neigborhood base at $w$.